# Can't indicate EOF through keyboard in Windows (Netbeans) , in a C program

Tags: c, eof

I took this snippet from *`The C programming Language`* by Dennis Ritchie. The idea is to count the number of characters through the input till `EOF` is reached.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

After I run this snippet, I entered a number of characters through the keyboard and indicated the `EOF` through `CTRL + Z` (and even tried `CTRL + C`). Instead of displaying the number of characters I got the following message in the console.

```
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 3s)
```

Been stuck on this for about 3 hours and feel like I'm wasting time over a trivial issue. Is there a different way to indicate `EOF` in the console? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @EugeneSh. looks like an **exact** dupe to me, so here we go ;)

Comment: Yes, the other post clarified all my doubts. Forgive me, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: A duplicate isn't necessarily something bad, so nothing to "forgive" here.